# Can I insert an external CSS link in Email Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template

Can I insert an external CSS link in Email Studio instead of creating a `<style> [css here] </style>` inside the  tag?

like inserting this code inside the header tag:
`< link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >`

Comment: Can you please post an example of your codE? It is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but it is not best practice, as you cannot rely on CDNs being 100% available. Best practice is to download the css file and upload it to your library. Then call the style sheets from your asset's library URL.